# PIL is pasting the original image instead of the cropped image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

i would like to get some help, why isn't Pillow putting the cropped image and not the original when i save the image?
It displays as cropped when i save it after cropping it, but when i paste it, it pastes the original instead, even after saving the cropped one and loading the cropped image and then pasting it.
Here's my code, to recreate the issue:

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps, ImageFont, ImageFilter

filename = "image to crop.png"
offset = 50,50
size = 400,400
avatar = Image.open(filename)
avatar = avatar.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
rad = 200
circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2, rad * 2), fill=255)
alpha = Image.new('L', _avatar.size, "white")
w, h = _avatar.size
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
alpha = alpha.resize(size)
avatar.putalpha(alpha)
background = Image.open("image to paste to.png")
background.paste(avatar, offset)
background.save("image with cropped image pasted.png")
```

Comment: Please make sure to show the **Minimum** Complete Verifiable Example as required by StackOverflow rules.

Comment: Please provide `image to crop.png` and `image to paste.png` and images showing what you get and what you expected.

Comment: i have fixed the issue, as i said below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found an solution! the problem was that i didn't assign the mask when pasting it!
here's the code that fixed it:

```
mask = Image.new("L", size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=255)
avatar = ImageOps.fit(avatar, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
avatar.putalpha(mask)
background = Image.open("welcomecardbackground.jpg")
background.paste(avatar, offset, mask)
```

instead of

```
circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2, rad * 2), fill=255)
alpha = Image.new('L', _avatar.size, "white")
w, h = _avatar.size
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
alpha = alpha.resize(size)
avatar.putalpha(alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 444, you are not assigning the output of the resize. `resize` returns a new image, it doesn’t modify the original image.

Comment: I assigned it, but it didn't fix the issue.